# cmake linker executable is not same with CMAKE_C_COMPILER

Tags: cmake

I'm using cmake to build cuda programs, setting CMAKE_C(CXX)_COMPILER and -ccbin flags to custom g++(5.3) executable, but linker still find the "/usr/bin/c++(4.9.2)" which cause an error.

So how to setting cmake linker executable path, is there something like CMAKE_C_LINKER?

Answer (score 0):

sry,     `CMAKE_<LANG>_LINK_EXECUTABLE`     variable solves this problem.